# C++ getline is undesirably removing whitespace

Tags: c++, c++11

Edit: It seems unlikely that is is actually an issue with getline and c++ and more likely an issue with my files. Apologies for the inconvenience of this post.

So, this is a weird situation I'm having, getline is on (rare) ocassion removing spaces from my lines. I am reading the first line from a file in the following way:

```
std::getline(annotationsFile, firstLine)
```

Now, the program is reading multiple files in the format "string int", ex:

```
upstream: 26019
```

Almost always this behaves as expected, I get the first line of the file. But for some reason I have a single file (the one I used as an example for the file format), that is instead being parsed by getline as:

```
upstream:26019
```

Does anyone have any idea what could possibly be causing this?

It is important to note that the files are being created by humans in multiple text editors on multiple platforms, but I have three files from one person and two of them work as expected and just this one is giving me this funky error.

Edit: Minimal example

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::ifstream testFile("test.txt");
  std::string firstLine;

  std::getline(testFile, firstLine);

  std::cout << firstLine << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Just wondering... is this single file (you are having problem reading) formatted in unicode?

Comment: In my experience `std::getline` works as expected. There may be something in the way you have coded it or in the data that is causing this. If you provide the code and some data (as a minimal example producing the error) we may be able to see what's going wrong.

Comment: It may be worth opening the offending file in a hex editor and posting the hex codes of the offending line in the question.

Comment: I have added a minimal code example the produces the error with the file still. It is possible the single file was formatted in unicode, and I will look into getting the hex codes.

Comment: There is something missing from this minimal example (which is supposed to run for us to test)

Comment: You are missing `#include <string>`  If you don't have the right includes, it is possible for a different `std::getline` to be used, or break in other unusual ways.  Actually, your code relies on `<string>` for the `string firstLine` variable itself, the `getline` call, and the insertion of `std::cout << firstLine`.  Any of those could act weird.

Comment: You should simply output the character codes (a.k.a. encoding values) and see what they are.

Comment: Well, my guess is some sort of file corruption or something. While I was attempting to read it in hexedit for the hex codes, the space was no longer present in the viewing. Which baffles me, because the line I quoted was a direct copy paste from the file itself. In any advent, I have lost my ability to reproduce this error. But I think it's less likely this is a c++ issue and more likely something with unix. @wendelbsilva do you know something about unicode that could cause this?

Comment: An immediate guess would be that the character between `upstream:` and `26019` is not really a space, but something completely different. When you preview you file in some text viewer/editor, it happens to display it visually as a space. But when you output the same character through `cout` it is not displayed at all. Open your original file in hex viewer and take a closer look at that character code. Is it really a space?

Comment: @Ben I've seen some cases that I though it was a space (0x20) but the computer didnt 'agree' with me. Something like [this](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html). [This link](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html) shows a list of spaces in unicode.. but I dont know how `std::string` handles most of it.

Comment: @AnT As mentioned I lost the original culprit file in trying to transfer it to my windows machine with hexedit, and a space is no longer displayed at all. I am willing to blame it on unicode, because I do believe it was created on a mac using textedit and possibly using UTF-8.

I feel wrong marking this question as answered, since the question title isn't correct, but it seems more and more likely the culprit was the character itself and not C++ at all, so what should be done with the question.